# How to scrape multiple urls using single xpath using selenium in python?

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

```
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()
mydriver.get(baseurl)
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchboxTxtBox']).clear()
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchboxTxtBox']).send_keys(searchbox)
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()

data = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('*//div[@class="product-result clearfix"]//h3//a//@href')

for element in data:
    print element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

On executing above code, it's throwing error:

```
the given selector is either invalid or does not result in a Web Element.
```

I need to scrape mutliple urls kindly help

Comment: Could post the exact error message? Along with the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: the exact error code is :selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector *//div[@class="product-result clearfix"]//h3//a//@href is either invalid or does not result in a web element.

Comment: Can you share the html?